# How do I use the scale function to make my variable have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1?

Tags: r, standard-deviation, mean

I have a variable that I need to scale to make sure that I have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. How do I do this on R/R Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

juste use scale()

```
x <- 1:1000
mean(scale(x))
> 0
sd(scale(x))
> 1
```

Comment: But that just changes all of the figure in the variable from 1 to 1000